# CSS div with relative positioning not working right in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-position

I'm placing a big image on top of a couple div layers with relative positioning. I'm also using top: -170px; to pull the image up to exactly where I need it to be. It works perfectly in Firefox, but in IE it won't adjust the position of the blue bar beneath it to account for the negative top positioning.

If I don't make sense, you can have a look at the live development site:

http://www.suncastmedia.com/clients/ezbook/

You'll see what I mean if you look in both firefox and IE.  Here is my CSS for these specific divs as well.

```
#red-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 343px;
  background: url('../images/bg-red.png') top left repeat-x;
  text-align: left;
}

#red-box-text {
  position: relative;
  left: 70px;
  top: 45px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: helvetica;
  width: 451px;
}

#spacer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
}

#blue-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 29px;
  background: url('../images/bg-blue.png') top left repeat-x;
}

#pic-globe {
  position: relative;
  top: -170px;
  left: 52%;
  background: url('../images/pic-globe.png') top left no-repeat;
  width: 506px;
  height: 471px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could switch `#pic-globe` and `#red-box-text` around, then add `float: right;` to `#pic-globe`. Generally, if you are using huge, negative margins, there might be an easier way to do it.